# How to retrieve(get) huge amount of data using linq(Entity Framework 5) with faster time

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

One of the order in our database has huge amount of records(> 500,000). When I attempted to get all records and map them to domain model, Its taking forever (linq call). The following sample code will describe what I did...

```
int OrderId = 123456;
int pagesize = 100;

using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    var orderDetails = dbContext.orderDetailEntity
        .Where(i => i.Orders.OrderID == OrderId)
        .OrderBy(o => o.orderDetailStatus);

    var orderDetailModel = Mapper
        .Map<IEnumerable<OrderDetailModel>>(orderDetails.Take(PageSize));         
 }
```

For more information Orders entity and OrderDetail entity has relationships. So on the above query I am trying to get all OrderDetail for the specific. But It is taking forever cos of huge amount of data(More than half a million records).

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue? 
I really appreciate you

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't put code in comments, [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35853255/edit) and put the info there. Also, if you are using Automapper with EntityFramework you should not use `Mapper.Map` and instead use it's [Queryable Extenstions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions). `orderDetailModel = orderDetails.Take(PageSize).ProjectTo<OrderDetailModel>().ToList();`

Comment: Have you checked the generated SQL and query execution plan? Have you tried to run that SQL directly against the database and measure its performance?

Comment: Do you have lazy loading on? I've had bad experiences with automapper and lazy loading - namely that automapper will trigger the navigation properties to load

Comment: @ Scott Chamberlain the problem is on the linq call(Where clause)

Comment: Are you certain the bottleneck is EF?  Have you attached a profile to see where the most time is being spent?

Comment: Do you have the proper indexes on your table?

Comment: @Rob I did not touch the lazy loading. It means its on default(means its on). Do u have any idea how to off it. how can I get the Orders entity?

Answer (score 1):

From experience, I'd never use Linq to get anything more than 100k records again. I was in a similar situation not too long ago with a similar amount of records, the one thing I would do differently is to get this amount of data using raw SQL queries.

That said, here are 2 things I did that minimized execution time dramatically:
1) Paging - Whatever you plan to do with these order objects - use paging as best you can (`.Skip .Take()`)

2) If the order objects are used only to display info on screen, adding `.AsNoTracking()`  can help minimize execution time. (A quick google search can outline reasons why)

```
    dbContext.orderDetailEntity
.AsNoTracking()
.Where(i => i.Orders.OrderID == OrderId)
.OrderBy(o => o.orderDetailStatus);
```

*TL;DR Don't use Linq to Entities - use a simple SQL query instead.*

Comment: Linq itself is not the problem, entity framework causes the trouble.

Comment: I'd agree to a certain extent but I'd also say that running SQL through the context still reduces execution time ten fold.

Comment: Data context in linq2sql is actually quite fast. It is faster than querying in SQL management studio btw. You can beat it with hard wired instantiation from SqlDataReader by 10%-30%, but You would have hard time to write alternative to `Translate` function that is faster. I repeat, EF is the problem, not linq.